# Как найти в массиве элемент undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив

```
Array [ "121", undefined , "123" ]
```

Как написать условие которое выполнится если в массиве есть `undefined` и не выполнится если `undefined`ов нет , и массив выглядит например?

```
Array [ "121", "115" , "123" ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (array.includes(undefined)) {...}
```